Fix csv line splitting
I have a csv file data like below with nearly 1 million records
sno, name, address, mobile
1,  shekar, hyderabad, 651584651
2, naveen, ban
galore, 61353384
3, eeshwar, warangal, 65133133
What I want is like below
sno, name, address, mobile
1,  shekar, hyderabad, 651584651
2, naveen, bangalore, 61353384
3, eeshwar, warangal, 65133133
enter image description here
can anyone help me on this to fix with any shortcut?
I tried resetting each line by line manually, but still there are thousands of lines like above.

Write a program to do it. Shouldn't take you more than a couple of minutes.

I'm not sure what program you are referring to? Is it sql program or is there any separate program for csv file also?

SQL is not mentioned at all in your question.

In Notepad++ the CSV Lint plug-in has a Replace CRLF option, you can replace newlines with <br> or \par or space or just with nothing https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/tree/master/docs#reformat

If your csv data is like this:
sno, name, address, mobile
1, shekar, hyderabad, 651584651
2, naveen, ban
galore, 61353384
3, eeshwar, Warangal, 65133133

Then the file is simply incorrectly formatted and no application, script or database will be able to parse it.
The correct way to format carriage return/line feed within a cell value of a csv file, is to add quotes around it, so something like this:
sno, name, address, mobile
1, shekar, hyderabad, 651584651
2, naveen, "ban
galore", 61353384
3, eeshwar, Warangal, 65133133

When it's formatted like this, then scripts like Python will be able to read it correctly and you could automatically remove all cariage return within cell values. But unfortunately, as it is now, I don't think there's a way to fix it without at least some manual editing. Either add the quotes or remove the carriage return/newlines yourself by hand.
Is it possible to just send the data file back to who ever provided it and ask them to format it correctly?

Well, yes I tried to edit the data manually since it has thousands of incorrect formatted lines, I sent it back to the provider to send correctly formatted csv file. Before that just wanted to check if there is any possibility to find short form to edit all lines at once. Thank you for your response .
